# (Cucumber) What's the difference between Background and Before tag

Tags: tags, cucumber

As I know, the @Before hooks are executing before every scenario(s), and now I've met with the Background tag, but it seems to me it has the exact same functionality as the @Before tag except it's own steps.
Can anybody explain what is the diff.s in real life? when I have to use Background instead of Before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference), here is what `Before` does:

> Before hooks will be run before the first step of each scenario. They
>   will run in the same order of which they are registered.

And here is what `Background` does:

> Background allows you to add some context to the scenarios in a single feature. A Background is much like a scenario containing a
>   number of steps. The difference is when it is run. The background is
>   run before each of your scenarios but after any of your Before Hooks.

In facts, as you noticed already, their structures are a little bit different.
The common practice is to use them as follows:

- Use `Background` when you provide customer-readable pre-conditions to your scenarios
- Use `Before` when you have to do some technical setup before your scenarios

But the main thing to understand here is the order of the operations:

**Before Hook 1 -> Before Hook 2 -> ... -> Background -> Scenario**

They just represent different levels of pre-conditions.